# Display angle of each line feature within a specific field for that layer using UpdateCursor method

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, line, features, angles

[image]So I want to calculate angles for each line feature layer using UpdateCursor method. So far I have progressed with the code but what it is doing is; it is giving the result of the last feature angle and substituting it for all the fields. I tried to avoid that function calling and now I am getting this error.
I have a polyline layer in a GDB consisting of smaller line features, I want to calculate the angle as in orientation of each line feature and update them in a marked field above in the attribute table.
Since I am new to this, I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Is there some other concrete method to do this?

Here is my code:

```py
count1 = 0
spatial_Reference = arcpy.Describe(output_split_merge_fibre_drop_sheath2).shapeFieldName
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output_split_merge_fibre_drop_sheath2, ["Fibre_SH_D", "SHAPE@", "OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                shape = row[1]
                count1 = count1+1
                feature = row.append(shape)
                x1 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.51, True).firstPoint.X
                x2 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.49, True).firstPoint.X
                y1 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.51, True).firstPoint.Y
                y2 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.49, True).firstPoint.Y
                radian = math.atan2((y1 - y2), (x1 - x2))
                row[0] = str(radian)
                print(row[0])
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The error message I am getting is:-

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'positionAlongLine'

Comment: First rule of cursors: Never nest DA cursors. Second rule of cursors (experts only): If you must nest cursors, make sure your loop variables don't conflict. You don't need the Search cursor at all, then you can start paying attention to your update loop code. You're also using non-DA cursor syntax.

Comment: @vince Yeah i just noted that and wont be doing that but still the same problem appears. how to solve the spatial reference issue?

Comment: Your code, as written, can't run (bad indentation and dangling except). Your field list is too short. The WHERE constraint is invalid. And row.setValue should fail (invalid usage). You also haven't described the data or what you are attempting. This makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: @Vince have a polyline layer in a GDB consisting of smaller line features, i want to calculate the angle as in orientation of each line feature and update them in a separate field in attribute table.

Comment: @Vince i have updated my code, please see the new error. Thank you

Comment: Yes, DA cursor rows are just lists, and don't have setter/getter functions. Use the documentation samples from the right function.

Comment: Your description is unclear. Giving an example *in the body of the question* would make it more clear.  `positionAlongLine` is ***very*** expensive. You should only execute it once (put the result in a variable, then access X and Y in place)

Comment: Hey @vince i tried to correct my code since DA.Update Cursor is a list I tried to correct using append method but now it cant use positionAlongLine(). Please suggest me something ?

Comment: You already have `shape`, so `feature = shape` (or just replace "feature" with "shape"). Again, your `positionAlongLine` is wasteful: `p1 = shape.positionAlongLine(0.49, True).firstPoint` ...

Comment: If you are not concerned about using radians you could use bearing? If so this is done with the [Add geometry Attributes tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm).

Comment: @Hornbydd hey that's a great workaround. it's just a one-line code then no requirement of using DA at all.

Comment: @Vince thanks a lot mate that worked out perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me out, I was struggling for weeks at this. You guys are great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this:

```py
count1 = 0
spatial_Reference = arcpy.Describe(output_splitLine_fibre_duct3).shapeFieldName
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output_splitLine_fibre_duct3, ["Fibre_D", "SHAPE@", "OBJECTID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        count1 = count1+1
        feature = row[1]
        p1 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.51, True).firstPoint
        p2 = feature.positionAlongLine(0.49, True).firstPoint
        radian = math.atan2((p1.Y - p2.Y), (p1.X - p2.X))
        row[0] = str(radian)
        print(row[0])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the angles in degrees use this one line code.

```
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(output_split_merge_fibre_drop_sheath2, Geometry_Properties= "LINE_BEARING")
```